# Copy card to top of new column by default, rather than bottom

Tags: trello

Is it possible when copying / duplicating a card in Trello to set the card to go to the top of the column you are copying / duplicating it to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes!

When you copy a card you should see the "Copy to..." options appear that allow you to select the Board, List and Position you want the copy to go to.  Just click each button to change the default selections.

Position means 1 is top of the list.  Default position is usually LAST on the list, however many cards there are in that list.

If you want to put the copied card into the top 9 entries in the list, tap that number (1 - 9) after clicking on the position button. (tapping 1 will put the card first in the list)

Comment: Thanks, but does this change the default ? When i go to copy i get the column, and position i want to copy it to, but when i change the column, the position auto changes to the last positon in the new column, id like it to be default to the first position in the new column. This dosnt matter when there are only a couple of cards in each column, but when there is 100 its allot to scroll through each time to get back to the top.

Comment: No, it does not change the default behaviour, however, all you need to do instead of scrolling is type 1 and it will take you to number 1 position.  That is hit 1 when you see the list of number positions.

Answer (score -1):

No, you cannot set a new card to appear in the top position by default.